# Best Way to parse File

Tags: vb.net

I have a string with following format

```
Zone: 1 Events: 3
Zone: 2 Events: 7
```

i am parsing the file with following code

```
Dim strarr() As String
strarr = Str.Split("/n")
for i = 0 to 2
    dim strarrNew() as string
    strarrNew = strarr(i)Split(" ")
    use value strarrNew(0)
        use value strarrNew(1)    
next
```

and i am using values directly but if their is a mistake in the string input

```
Zone:1Events: 3
```

spaces are missing than code will not work.
What would be the best way to parse file.

Comment: your question is not clear enough, could you please explain what will be your expected output?

Comment: For the first line my expected output would be 1,3

Comment: For the second line my output would be 2,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adopt this solution only if all the inputs from the file is of the same format:

```
  For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("F:\sample.txt")
       Dim strarrNew() As String = line.Split(":"c.ToCharArray())
       Dim zone As Integer = CInt(Val(strarrNew(1)))
       Dim events As Integer = CInt(Val(strarrNew(2)))
      'Perform your operations
  Next
```

Comment: No point converting one char to a char array, you could use `line.Split(":"c)` instead. Also `Val` returns a `Double` so `CInt` or `Int32.Parse` / `Int32.TryParse` is a better option here